Proving Linear Dependence from Cross Product Sum J
Prove that if $\vec{u} \times \vec{v} + \vec{v} \times \vec{w} +
\vec{w} \times \vec{u} = \overrightarrow{0}$, then $\{\vec{u},
\vec{v}, \vec{w}\}$ are linearly dependent.
Solution: Consider the cross product $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$. It is orthogonal to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. The same is true for $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$ and $\vec{w} \times \vec{u}$. Thus, all three cross products are orthogonal to their arguments. Consider the equation
$$
\vec{u} \times \vec{v} + \vec{v} \times \vec{w} + \vec{w} \times \vec{u} = \overrightarrow{0}
$$
Let us take the scalar product of both sides of the equation by $\vec{u}$
$$
\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v} + \vec{v} \times \vec{w} + \vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = \vec{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{0}
$$
Since $\vec{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{0} = 0$, we have
$$
\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) + \vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) + \vec{u} \cdot (\vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = 0
$$
Note that $\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) = 0$ (the scalar product of a vector and the vector product with it is equal to zero). Also, $\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = 0$ for the same reason. Therefore, $\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = 0$. This means that the vector $\vec{u}$ is orthogonal to the vector $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$. Similarly, let us take the scalar product of the original equation by $\vec{v}$
$$
\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v} + \vec{v} \times \vec{w} + \vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = \vec{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{0}
$$
Since $\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) = 0$ and $\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = 0$, $\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = 0$ remains. This means that the vector $\vec{v}$ is orthogonal to the vector $\vec{w} \times \vec{u}$. Repeating similar reasoning for the vector $\vec{w}$, we obtain $\vec{w} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) = 0$. This means that the vector $\vec{w}$ is orthogonal to the vector $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$. Hence,
$$
\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = 0, \quad \vec{v} \cdot (\vec{w} \times \vec{u}) = 0, \quad \vec{w} \cdot (\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) = 0
$$
Let $\{\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}\}$ be linearly independent. Then $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$, $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$ and $\vec{w} \times \vec{u}$ will not be equal to zero, and they will all be mutually orthogonal. However, since $\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = 0$ (and similarly for other cases), a contradiction
Question: A triple $(u, v, w)$ is linearly dependent if and only if $[u, v, w] = (u \times v) \cdot w$ is equal to zero. You could use only this fact and finish the problem, right?

Does this answer your question? Coplanar vectors It explains that you can indeed conclude with this argument, right after your 'Therefore, $\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = 0$'.

Yes, you can. In fact, you can use it earlier in your argument, right after

This means that the vector $\vec u$  is orthogonal to the vector $\vec v \times \vec w$

since both the line above and $(\vec u \times \vec v) \cdot \vec w = 0$ mean that $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ lie on a single 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. This is true because being orthogonal to single vector means lying on the 2-dimensional subspace orthogonal to it, and in case of $\vec w \times \vec v$ this plane is spanned exactly by $\vec w$ and $\vec v$.
